# Create object of anonymous class

Tags: java, oop

We have inner class

```
class OuterClass
{
  public Iterator getIterator(final String name)
  {
    class LocalIterator implements Iterator
    {
        public Iterator next()
        {
            return new LocalIterator();
        }
    }
    return new LocalIterator();
 }
}
```

Is it possible to make an anonymous class with all functionality of Local iterator and make getIterator return object of that anonymous class? The main problem is  - what should be instead of

```
  return new LocalIterator();
```

Comment: Do you really want to return an `Iterator` that yields other `Iterator` (recursively) ?

Comment: return new Iterator() { .... your code here ....  };

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure if I understand your question correctly. But if you want to use an anonymous class you can do:

```
class OuterClass {

    public Iterator<Object> getIterator(final String name) {
        return new Iterator<Object>() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                // validate if there is a next object
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Object next() {
                // get the next object and return it, throw an exception if there is no next object
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In general, you are always able to create an instance of any interface using anonymous classes (see, e.g., http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm). You also have access to the `name` parameter within the class and to the `this` instance of the outer class using `OuterClass.this`.

Answer (score 2):

You should give this design pattern a try:

```
class OuterClass implements Iterable {
    ....

    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new Itr();
    } 

    private class Itr implements Iterator {
        ....
    }
}
```

1. it doesn't expose iterator implementation
2. it is easy to read and maintain this code
3. `Itr` instances can be used everywhere as a common `Iterator`

Comment: Why upvotes? This answer is not fit the question about **anonymous class**.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `OuterClass` implements `Iterable` in order to be usable with the foreach loop. Then in `iterator()` you could return an instance of an anonymous iterator (replace `T` with the concrete type you need).

```
public class OuterClass<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```